# Should I use beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: for all HTTP connections?

Tags: ios, multitasking

I am developing an iOS application that has the capability of uploading data to a remote endpoint.  Because a good user experience would involve being able to leave the app to go do some other task while it is uploading, should I initiate **all** my uploads with the `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` API?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. That is consistent with one of the design patterns described in [the application design guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html):

> Wrap any long-running critical tasks with
>   `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` and `endBackgroundTask:`
>   calls. This protects those tasks in situations where your application
>   is suddenly moved to the background.

Then in the expiration handler you can mark the upload as incomplete, and return to it in `applicationDidBecomeActive:`.

Answer (score 0):

well, in my point of view,  `applicationDidBecomeActive:` method won't allow you handle something special, such as network access, location service, blue tooth function and so on. But i'm not skill enough to prove it...